# Static values stored in UIView not deleted when VC is destroyed

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have two different View controllers in my app. Let them be A (first ViewController) , B (Second ViewController). My ViewController B has a view called NewsView which is reused multiple times in ViewController B. NewsView has a static variable `articles` that stores the number of times NewsView is displayed thus far in the ViewController B.

```
class NewsView: UIView {
    static var articles: Int = 0
}
```

Now when I go back to View Controller A and then come to ViewController B. My NewsView still contains `articles` value which was calculated previously. Shouldn't it be deleted when ViewController B is destroyed? If it doesn't get destroyed what is the best way to clear it when view controller B is closed. My architecture prevents accessing views from viewController

Comment: Thats how `static` works - the value is shared across all instances, and is not tied to any specific instance. If you remove `static` each instance of `NewsView` will get their own value.

Comment: Yes. I want a shared value across all views. My question is, The view is coupled with the ViewController. The View's Definition is present in ViewController B. Now when View Controller B is destroyed, everything that is related to ViewContoller B should be destroyed right including the View and it's the static variable?

Comment: No - `static` variables exist even without any instance of the object. You can freely access them using `NewsView.articles` from any place in your code, even if it is not present on screen. If you need to use `static` you will need to remember to reset the value in appropriate place and moment manually.

Answer (score 0):

The variable should be declared in the view controller B and accessed by the view via a delegate method. So the view can update it and it is deleted when the controller is destroyed.